# Как footer заложить на низ?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Никак не могу решить проблему. Footer никак не хочет прижиматься к низу, почему? Подскажите.
https://bitly.su/WHVL

Как бы проблему решил тем, что тегу `main` дал высоту `185vh`. Но это не совсем правильное решение. Как можно решить проблему(по другому)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Footer (подвал сайта) всегда внизу:

```js
var i = 1;

function addtext(el) {
  a = el.parentNode;
  a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML + '<h1>' + (i++) + '</h1>test<br>test';
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html>body #all {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#all {
  height: 100%;
  width: 972px;
  position: relative;
  color: #404040;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#empty,
#footer {
  height: 32px;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 970px;
  display: block;
  background: url('/images/footer.gif');
  border: 1px #376FA7 solid;
}

#main {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#content {
  padding-left: 40px;
  width: 932px;
  border: 1px #376FA7 solid;
}

body {
  background: #D1EAF4;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

h3 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <h3>Контент страницы</h3>
      <br><input type="button" value="Добавить контента" onclick="addtext(this);">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both">
  <div id="empty">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="footer">
    <h3>Эта надпись снизу сколько бы контента не было на странице</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: вы же изменили css  у него там grid

Comment: Вы правы, но по аналогии - принцип один, и по примеру можно сваять что и в этом случае - кроме того, можно попробовать вставить соответствующий "заполняющий" блок вне грида - безболезненно и не нарушая остального кода - такой подход применялся на сайтах портального типа с различными модульными решениями (и шаблонами) разделов - для придания общего стиля и прочего.