# Как прижать footer к низу страницы если нету вертикального скрола

Tags: html, css

Как это сделать в том случае если данных на сайте нету. На данный момент он у меня по центру экрана. Очень не красиво смотрится.

Comment: См. Как footer заложить на низ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011962/Как-footer-заложить-на-низ/1012000#1012000

Comment: неее, там фиксированная позиция, всегда виден футер

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Флексы:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Альтернативный вариант:

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px); /*200px - сумма footer и header */
  background: pink;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: когда использую height: 100vh; появляется скролл по вертикали

Comment: мой косяк, указал box-sizing: border-box; и все четко стало

Answer (score -1):

Ну я на этот случай всегда устанавливаю минимальную высоту элемента. А в блоке article если нет никакого контента то добавляю блок "Нет записей", к примеру.

```
<header></header>
<article></article>
<footer></footer>
```

```
header, article, footer
{
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: при таком раскладе блок footer начинается по середине экрана

Comment: Если тебе нужно чтобы блок footer начинался за пределами рабочей области экрана то нужно так и писать. Чтобы получить максимальное количество полезных ответов надо правильно выражать свои мысли.

Comment: читайте внимательнее вопрос, footer должен быть снизу экрана если нету вертикального скрола, а если он есть то следовательно он за пределами рабочей области экрана

Comment: За этим ничего не следует так как это можно интерпретировать как угодно. Вопрос звучит :  "Как прижать footer к низу страницы если нету вертикального скрола". Я пояснил что страница просто не должна быть меньше размера экрана так как это не красиво. И исправить это можно установив минимальные размеры блоков и заполнить блок контента информационным блоком "Записи отсутствуют". Это альтернативный вариант решения вашей проблемы. Для более точных ответов нужно предоставлять максимальное кол-во информации со скриншотами и кодом и четким описанием проблемы.

Comment: Вы писали:"Если тебе нужно чтобы блок footer начинался за пределами рабочей области экрана то нужно так и писать." вот это как раз можно интерпретировать как угодно. Footer должен быть снизу экрана а вы пишите за пределами. Серьезно? Если вам не хватает описания проблемы просите скриншоты, код. Я посчитал они излишни и судя по скорому ответу на этот вопрос они и не нужны были

Comment: а вообще приведенный вами код не рабочий, footer не снизу экрана. ОН начнется с 600 px прям по центру экрана